# Lucene xml retrieval

Tags: java, xml, solr, lucene

I have an xml file with like 500 fields,
I have looked into the apache digester option,
but involves a lot of work. I have to create many classes to cover these 500 fields.
Is there any other way for me to get 
suppose i search for 10013,i can get the matched  document name, but can i get the name field in the below xml syntax.

```
<contact type="individual"> <name>name feild</name>
    <address>999 W. Prince St.</address>
    <city>New York</city>
    <province>NY</province>
    <postalcode>10013</postalcode>
    <country>USA</country>
    <telephone>1-212-345----</telephone>
</contact>
```

Or does apache solr give me a better api for this.

Comment: I sure hope Zane isn't a real person.

Comment: You have only 1 XML file? Can you provide a snippet? What are your search needs?

Comment: I cannot provide the snippet. my search needs are to search by fields.

Comment: Are you familiar with http://wiki.apache.org/solr/SchemaXml and http://wiki.apache.org/solr/SolrQuerySyntax ?